# Cannot get 3D to work with 3D BluRay

Tags: blu-ray, 3d, home-theater, powerdvd

I set up a home theater system that's supposed to support 3D.  Unfortunately, the 3D content does not appear in 3D, despite all components appearing to work properly.

The components, in order from data to eyes, are:

- Cyberlink PowerDVD 16
- Windows 10
- [Radeon HD 6850](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814131374) video card, using AMD's official driver version 15.201.1151.1008
- [Monoprice High Speed HDMI cable](http://www.monoprice.com/product?c_id=102&cp_id=10240&cs_id=1024004&p_id=3663&seq=1&format=2) that claims to support 3D
- [Epson PowerLite Home Cinema 3500](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1081978-REG/epson_v11h651020_powerlite_home_cinema_3500.html), connected to video card using HDMI
- [Epson ELPGS03 RF 3D glasses](http://www.epson.com/cgi-bin/Store/jsp/Product.do?sku=V12H548006)

When I play 3D content:

- PowerDVD reports that the 3D Display is "HDMI 1.4 enabled 3D TV (1080p 24Hz)"
- The projector enters 3D mode, making the screen brighter
- The 3D glasses are shuttering

However, the picture still looks 2D: one can watch it without the 3D glasses.  There are no overlapping copies of the picture, as I've seen at IMAX 3D, so I'm unsure where the 3D effect would come from. Neither I nor my partner perceive the picture to be in 3D.

**Some more data:**

Windows 10 has 3D support enabled for this display device:

[image: Windows 10 has 3D support enabled for this display device]

Catalyst driver hardware stats:

[image: Catalyst driver hardware stats]

I'd appreciate any advice for finding the missing link.

Comment: Is there anything of interest under `Gaming > 3D Application Settings` in your CCC?

Comment: @jatuttle0, nothing relevant: http://philip.mailworks.org/stackexchange/2016/3d/Catalyst%203D%20Application%20Settings.png

Comment: Can you add PowerDVD to the application settings? `+ Add ...`

Comment: @jatuttle0, when I try to add it, it says, "An AMD pre-defined application profile already exists for the selected application. Do you want to override the pre-defined profile?" When I say no, it cancels the add.

Comment: Hmm. No direct experience with 3d blurays, but the only things that come to mind are making sure your cables are HDMI 1.4 compliant, rebooting all hardware, checking source video metadata to ensure you aren't looking at a 2d video file

Answer (score 1):

Between me and another person who was experiencing the same problem, we determined that the fault lies with PowerDVD 16.  We were both using the 30-day trial, and apparently the trial version does not support 3D BluRays, while giving the impression (in the UI) that 3D is active!

The [download page of PowerDVD](http://www.cyberlink.com/downloads/trials/powerdvd-ultra/download_en_GB.html) says:

> **Limitations**
>
> Does not support the playback of HEVC/H.265/Blu-ray 3D content.

The other person bought the full version of PowerDVD, and now 3D works.